# On the definition of algebra .

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $\mathscr{C}$ a monoidal category with monoidal product $A\circ B$. Is defined the bicategory of bimodules $Mod(\mathscr{C})$ on $\mathscr{C}$  (see [Gray] p. 46).
Its objects are $\mathscr{C}$-monoids (on some object $X$ of $\mathscr{C}$, this means on the monoidal category of endomorphisms of $X$). Then a  $Mod(\mathscr{C})$-monoid on  $R$ (then $R$ is a $\mathscr{C}$-monoid) is a $(R, R)$-bimodule , with a composition morphims $A\otimes_R A\to A$ or equivalently a morphim $A\circ A\to A$ such that the compositions $(A\circ R)\circ A \to  A\circ A \to  A$ and $(A\circ R)\circ A\cong A\circ (R\circ A) \to  A\circ A \to   A $ are equal.

Now, $A$ isn't exactly what is called or defined a $R$-algebra (see for example ALGEBRA volumes of Bourbaki), because in general $ R\circ A\to A $ is different to $ R\circ A\cong A\circ  R \to A $.

In fact the usual definition of algebra requires $r\cdot  a= a \ast  r$ for $a\in A, r\in R$, where "$\circ $" is the left action, and "$\ast $" the right action (further $R$ is commutative and these actions are the some).

**Question:** If we put $\mathscr{C}:= (Ab, \otimes)$ (abelian group, with $\mathbb{Z}$-tensor product, than $R$ is a  ring )  what kind of (quasi, pseudo, para ecc) "algebra" is $A$?  Is it known in Math literature?

[Gray] Formal category theory LNM 391, J.W. Gray.